# Microsoft Word Macro to delete everything other than text

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to create a macro in word that deletes everything other than text.

So charts/tables/excel tables/images.

I've tried recording one and manipulating it but to no avail.

This is working for images & charts but not tables/excel tables.

```
Sub deleteimages()
    Dim i As Integer

    With ActiveDocument
        For i = 1 To .InlineShapes.Count
            .InlineShapes(i).ConvertToShape
        Next i

        Dim Shp As Shape
        For Each Shp In ActiveDocument.Shapes
            If Shp.Type = msoTextBox Then Shp.Delete
        Next Shp

        For Each Shp In ActiveDocument.Shapes
            If Shp.Type = msoTable Then Shp.Delete
        Next Shp

        ActiveDocument.Shapes.SelectAll
        Selection.Delete
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: MS Word has several inbuilt collections. Use them to delete unwanted items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This macro deletes Charts, MS Tables, Excel copied tables & images.

```
Sub deleteNoise()
Dim objPic As InlineShape
For Each objPic In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes
objPic.Delete
Next objPic
    Dim tbl As Table
    For Each tbl In ActiveDocument.Tables
        tbl.Delete
    Next tbl
        Dim shp As Shape
ActiveDocument.Shapes.SelectAll
        Selection.Delete
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

For tables, use this:

```
Sub deletetables()
    Dim i As Integer

    With ActiveDocument
        For i = .Tables.Count To 1 Step -1
            .Tables(i).Delete
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

The same logic use for charts and other objects.

For further information, please see: [Word Object Model Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb225019%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

By The Way: i suggest to delete objects starting from the last one, because of set of reasons. Another way is to use `Do While... loop`:

```
Do While ActiveDocument.Tables.Count>1
    ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Delete
Loop
```

Comment: Ended up getting a permission error with this one so i recreated mine (answered below)